# Excel VBA Delete Column from imported worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to import a worksheet from a closed file. Once the import is complete I want to delete a column from that worksheet and switch back to the primary worksheet. I tried using Columns(4).Delete and EntireColumns.Delete but there is no error and Excel takes no action. Any ideas on a better way I could do this?

```
'THIS CODE HANDLES THE IMPORT OF THE DATA
Sub ImportFile()

    'DEFINITIONS
    Dim fileImport As String
    Dim srcBook As Workbook

    ' TURNS OFF SCREEN UPDATING
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' THE FILE PATH
    fileImport = "PATH"
    'OPENS THE BOOK
    Set sourceB = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileImport)
    'COPYS THE SHEET
    sourceB.Sheets("Miscellaneous Holds").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets    (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    ' CLOSES THE BOOK
    srcBook.Close True

    'ENABLES SCREEN EDIT
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Sheets("Main").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe not working if you are not qualifying the sheet properly in your `Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete` statement...

So use `sourceB.Sheets("Miscellaneous Holds").Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete` instead....

If you don't want these changes to be saved in your source workbook then change the saveChanges parameter to false.

---

```
'THIS CODE HANDLES THE IMPORT OF THE DATA
Sub ImportFile()

    'DEFINITIONS
    Dim fileImport As String
    Dim srcBook As Workbook
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet

    ' TURNS OFF SCREEN UPDATING
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' THE FILE PATH
    fileImport = "PATH"
    'OPENS THE BOOK
    Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileImport)

    Set srcSheet = sourceB.Sheets("Miscellaneous Holds")

    srcSheet.Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete

    'COPYS THE SHEET
    srcSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    ' CLOSES THE BOOK
    srcBook.Close False

    'ENABLES SCREEN EDIT
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: That does work! but I'm getting a "Object variable or With block variable not set. I think this might have something to do with how I defined the DIMS.

Comment: Maybe.. You declare the workbook as `srcBook` but then refer to `sourceB`... This may be causing your error. Try changing the names so they are the same and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: That fixed it, it was a typo with srcBook :) Thank you!